# How to generate ion-select from ts for loop

Tags: angularjs, ionic3

I am new to Ionic .I want to generate an ion select option in html file from the ts file. In below code I have a for loop which executes 7 time and gives 7 different `this.newDate` value. I want every time a loop executes will create an ion-option in html file.

```
 viewTime(){

       let url = 'http://api.timezonedb.com/v2.1/get-time-zone?key=8304HG08V&format=json&by=zone&zone=Asia/Kolkata';

        this.http.request(url, this.config.options)
        .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe((response: any) => {
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.timestamp);

                    var data = response.timestamp - 19800 ;
                      const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
                    const time = datePipe.transform(data*1000, 'h:mm a');

                    //const datePipe = new DatePipe('en-US');
                    const serverDate = datePipe.transform(response.timestamp*1000, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
                    if(time >='16:00 PM'){

                        data = data+172800;

                        console.log("hello")
                    }

                    else{

                            data = data+86400;
                         console.log("exit")

                    }


     this.newDate = datePipe.transform(data*1000, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
        for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

               var value = data+(86400*i);
               this.newDate = datePipe.transform(value*1000, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
          }

                                }, (err) => {
                                let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
                                title: 'Error',
                                subTitle: 'Please check your credentials',
                                buttons: ['OK']
                                        });
                                 alert.present();
                                 });
                                 }
 }
```

How to solve this?

Comment: you should push your `this.newDate` values to an array and then bind that in `ngModel` of ion-select.

Comment: Thanks for reply...can you provide the code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you can use something like below.

**sample.ts**

```
export class Sample {

  dates;
  date;

  constructor() {

    this.dates = [];
  }

  viewTime(){

  for (var i = 1; i < 8; i++) {

    var value = data+(86400*i);
    this.newDate = datePipe.transform(value*1000, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    this.dates.push(this.newDate);

    }
  }
}
```

**sample.html**

```
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select a Date</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="date">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let date of dates"> {{date}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
```

I created a [working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-cdvvjc?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html) for you.

Comment: it is showing ion-select but as soon as i click any of the ion-option it gives this e ERROR Error: Error trying to diff ' 19/10/2018'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

Comment: The example which you provided also works only first time when the page refresh.

Comment: Ok I will fixed that issue. but I only try to give a solution what you ask is "How to generate ion-select from ts for loop"

Comment: @Saif khan I updated my answer. See it works for you.